# How to convert the date that have been retrieve from DB to only display d/mm/yyyy?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, date

I have this `21/10/1999` value manually inserted into the SQL database and when I retrieve it like this:

```
txtDOB.Text = readPatient["pDOB"].ToString();
```

It displays everything along with the time `12:00:00 AM`. My data type for my date column is `date`, not `datetime`. So why is it displays the time as well?

Comment: Because type to hold dates in C#/.NET is DateTime and it has time part. Use ToShortDateString() instead of ToString()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
((DateTime)readPatient["pDOB"]).ToString("d");
```

For a list of supported formats see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You may try

```
txtDOB.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(readPatient["pDOB"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Edit: Thanks to comments saw that forgot to cast to datetime

Comment: or simply `ToShortDateString` or `ToString("d")`. Btw, you need to cast the object to `DateTime` first, otherwise it will not compile.

Comment: Just a side question: why CultureInfo.InvariantCulture? dd/MM isn't for invariant culture so I suppose other formatting shouldn't be...

Comment: IT depends on the culture your application used on. Different time formats used in different cultures and using this format lets your user to see their accustomed format. Also Tim Schmelter's solution is shortcut for this.

Comment: You need to cast to DataTime first

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got your answer on how to properly format the value to a string without the time portion. But, no one has answered your other question:

> So why is it displays the time as well?

This is because of mappings between SQL and .NET. In .NET a SQL "date" is stored in a DateTime object which does have time as well. To see all mappings between SQL and .NET see this: [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
txtDOB.Text=Convert.toDateTime(readPatient["pDOB"]).ToString("d/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string format parameter of the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) to achieve any format you like,

like this:

```
TextBox1.Text =Convert.toDateTime(readPatient["pDOB"]).ToString("d/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the datetimepicker then go to properties. There you can format your datetimepicker. Change format to custom (there few selection there) then set custom (provided in the properties menu) table with yy-MM-dd,an

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(sqdr["invdate"].ToString());
dt.Date;  //To get the date only
```